# Reinforcement learning Portfolio management

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have created a reinforcement learning model related to fund and portfolio management. In the modeling phase, the result is good as it shows a positive return. However, during the testing phase, the result is null. Here is the reward function, how can I correct it?

```
# Define the reward function for the RL problem
def reward_function(state, action):
    # Calculate portfolio returns and risk based on action
    portfolio_returns = np.array(expected_asset_return) @ action
    portfolio_risk = np.sqrt(action @ var_cov @ action)

    # Calculate transaction cost
    delta_weights = np.abs(np.array(state) - action)
    transaction_cost = C * B * np.sum(delta_weights)

    # Calculate final reward
    reward = portfolio_returns - portfolio_risk - transaction_cost

    return reward
```

The result:

```
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Rendement total sur l'ensemble de test : 0.0
```

Comment: It would be worth tagging this question with a language. Is this Python?